# Problem with DateHistogram Epilog

Tags: bugs, date-and-time, histograms

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier and persisting through 13.3.0**

@Szabolcs reported this bug on the WRI Redmine bug tracker 11 months ago. It is still "In Progress".

---

`Epilog` in `DateHistogram` is incorrectly rendered.

```
$Version
(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)    

dates = {DateObject[{2021, 01, 10}], DateObject[{2021, 01, 10}], DateObject[{2021, 01, 12}]}

epilog = Inset[Framed[Grid[{{"Mean", 1.5}}, Alignment -> {{Left, Right}}]], Scaled[{1, 1}], ImageScaled[{1, 1}]];
```

The `epilog` looks fine

```
Graphics@epilog
```

[image]

When it is used in `DateHistogram`, `AbsoluteTime` is evaluated on the text.

```
DateHistogram[dates, "Day", Epilog -> epilog]
```

[image]

Reproducible on Wolfram Cloud "12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 16, 2020)"

This only happens with `DateHistogram`, it works fine with `Histogram`. I could find nothing in the documentation regarding the special behavior of `Epilog` in `DateHistogram`.

Is this a bug? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 8):

This is certainly a bug: All pairs `{a:(_String|_List), b_?(NumberQ[N@#]&)}` that appear *anywhere* in epilog/prolog are replaced with `{AbsoluteTime[a], b}`.

An example that shows various cases that trigger the mysterious behavior as well as possible work-arounds:

```
epilog2 = Inset[Framed[
    Grid[{{"FOO", 1.5}, 
        {"FOO", BAR[1.5]},
        {"FOO", "1.5"}, 
        {Defer@"FOO", 1.5},
        {FOO, 1.5},
        {{2021, 1, 1}, 1.5}, 
        {{2021, 1, 1}, "1.5"},
        {{2021, 1, 1}, 1.5, ""},
        {Defer@{2021, 1, 1}, 1.5}
        {{100}, 1.5},
        {Defer@{100}, 1.5}}, 
   Alignment -> {{Left, Right}}]], Scaled[{1, 1}],  ImageScaled[{1, 1}]];

DateHistogram[dates, "Day", Epilog -> epilog2]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
>  "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

An alternative work-around is to remove the option `Epilog` from `DateHistogram`, wrap it with `Show` and add the epilog in `Show`:

```
Show[DateHistogram[dates, "Day",  ImageSize -> Large], Epilog -> epilog2]
```

or

```
Show[DateHistogram[dates, "Day",  ImageSize -> Large], Graphics@epilog2]
```

[image]

The culprit is the replacement rule `` Charting`timeCoordRule `` applied to epilog (also prolog and axes origin) expressions inside the function `` Charting`iDateHistogram ``:

```
epilog2 /. Charting`timeCoordRule
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Its definition:

```
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal[Charting`timeCoordRule]
```

[image]